# can i trademark an image someone posted online from their friend

Tags: trademark

I really like a drawing someone posted. It was an image someone's friend drew for them so she could put it on her car. she was just showing it off in an online forum. thx

If I cant trademark it, can I redraw something similar and trademark my own drawing?

I want to use the drawing as a logo/image for my business.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a trademark that you can't legally copy, and you can't legally copy someone else's drawings without license.  See [copyright](/questions/tagged/copyright).